# Why cant a 64-bit value be accessed atomically on a 32-bit system?

Tags: linux, atomic

Reading upon Linux Scheduler from "https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l13.pdf"
I came across a statement :

> "A 64-bit value cannot be accessed atomically on a 32-bit machine"

My question is , why is it so ?

we can use locks to make it atomic, as described in the next bullet on the same article. If thats true, then what is meant by the quoted line.

Comment: I think they mean accessing atomically without locks. I.e. the load from memory itself is atomic.

Comment: Maybe its because we it will result in two separate memory access, and there is no guarantee  that both the access will be subsequent (no context switch)...

Comment: @tangrs You should make that an answer.

Comment: If the CPU can only read 32 bits at a time from memory/cache, reading 64 bits means 2 separate memory reads. Since a write can come in between those reads, the operation is not atomic without a lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, they probably mean that the load from memory itself isn't atomic.

A 64bit word on a 32bit machine might take two memory accesses to get the full word. During the two reads, a context switch could occur or may be overwritten by a DMA device. Therefore, you get a half correct value.